# How to run Visual Studio 2008 and WAMP server on same local machine running Windows7?

Tags: php, apache, visual-studio-2008, windows-7-x64, wampserver

I'm having a machine running on Windows 7. First I installed WAMP server on my local machine. It was working fine. Then I installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. From that time the WAMP server is not working at all. Means the **"W"** symbol of WAMP server gets **Green** but nothing is working like if I print **`http://localhost/abc`** or **`http://localhost/phpmyadmin`**. The page loader keeps on revolving and revolving and ultimately after long time error message comes. I gone into the details of this issue. Then I found Apache server is not running. Also I checked port 80 status. But nothing is worked for me till now. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

change your apache listen port
open this file `c:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\conf\httpd.conf`
find that line `Listen 80` in this file and change to other number example `Listen 8080` after that changed restart all wamp service and open your browser and test it again with `http://loacalhost:8080/`